# For which $x\gt 0$ does $\frac{x^n}{\sin(\pi\sqrt{3}n)}$ converge to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> find all reals $x>0$ for which the sequence $\frac{x^n}{\sin(\pi n\sqrt{3})}$ converge to $0$

---

*Added from comments*:
"I think we must have $0\lt x\lt 1$ but i have no idea how to prove it, it's obvious for $x\gt 1$ it diverges.

"well if we call $x_n$ this sequence then $x_n\geq x^n$ for $x\gt 1$, it's divergent."

Comment: Please show some work or explain why you are stuck, rather than simply order the group to solve the problem you were given.

Comment: Why are you putting your thoughts in comments instead of in your post?

Comment: What we want in this site is more than just "do my homework for me" which is what your original post looks like. Please put, **in the post**, your thoughts, where exactly you are stuck (and why). That will help readers know where you are, and tailor their responses in ways that are more likely to be helpful and at the appropriate level. Don't force them to wade through comment threads to find out what you are doing. And put more than just the question in the post itself, or people will read it as "Please do my homework for me" and vote it down and close it.